# Чем задокументировать фреймворк?

Tags: php, документация, фреймворк

есть некий php фреймворк, без документации. Необходимо описать функционирование, классы, методы.  Целевая аудитория -- будущие разработчики. Месторасположение -- в интернете. Нужно что то вроде вики, но не вики и не производные "викоиды"

Comment: Документацию обычно пишут прямо в коде

Comment: @andreymal далеко не всю документацию можно писать в коде. Ну и код вы не выложите как сайт.

Comment: @NickVolynkin во-первых, почти всю. Во-вторых, есть десятки инструментов, позволяющих выложить это как сайт :)

Comment: @andreymal как техписатель вам говорю, далеко не всю. Спецификации, требования, архитектурная, внедрение, whitepapers, пользовательская, туториалы для разработчиков - всё это нельзя положить в комментарии к коду. :)

Comment: @andreymal про инструменты согласен, просто надо выбрать и настроить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно документируют код с помощью нотации phpdoc и на основе этой нотации генерируют документацию, например с помощью [phpDocumentor](http://lifeexample.ru/razrabotka-i-optimizacia-saita/phpdoc-i-phpdocumentor.html) или [Doxygen](https://blog.ksdaemon.ru/2011/08/ispolzovanie-php-doc-doxygen-dlya-generacii-php-dokumentacii/)